# jquery .append not working as expected in IE

Tags: jquery

I have this section.

```
<section class="note">
    Content-0: SomeContent that needs to be removed. Anything below this stays.
    <br />
    <div class="content1">Content-1: Stays <br /><br /></div>
    <div class="content2"><p>Content-2: Stays</p></div>
</section>
```

What I want is on the page load remove Content-0 line and just have two s.
So I have this code on load...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var content1 = $('section.note div.content1');
        var content2 = $('section.note div.content2');

        $('section.note').html('').append(content1).append(content2);
        alert($('section.note').html());
    });
</script>
```

But it is behaving weird in IE(all versions). In IE 10 it is appending divs but with no content. In other IE versions it's not removing Content-0 and keeping all stuff as it is.

It works fine in FireFox.

Comment: What exactly is "weird"? Please explain what happens and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @FelixKling It's all in the link that I posted above.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Can you include a demo on jsbin, jsfiddle, or pastebin rather than your domain that may not exist in 5 days?

Comment: @Kevin I can but how does it matter, I full code up there.

Comment: @oms it matters because without it your question is not useful to future visitors, thus making answers pointless. Ideally you should include simplified demo that you can post here on so completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var content1 = $('section.note div.content1').clone();
    var content2 = $('section.note div.content2').clone();

    $('section.note').html('').append(content1).append(content2);
    alert($('section.note').html());
});
```

Basically what was happening is, here: `var content1 = $('section.note div.content1')` you are referring to the actual DOM element, then you first remove the DOM element with `$('section.note').html('')` and then append those references again, but in the meantime the text has disappeared by setting the html to ''. So cloning those divs fixes it, as you are not referencing the original DOM element anymore.

Comment: Works fine but still wonder why would it work in FF and not in IE.

Comment: It's a different browser with a different Javascript engine, I have never delved into the exact differences between the Javascript engines on browsers, but I can see how they might do some things the other way around, resulting in different outcomes, it might be milliseconds we're talking about. They're all trying to be the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though IE is cleaning up the elements so quickly that jquery isn't able to move them correctly because they were removed by the preceding `.html('')` call. You can solve that by either cloning, or detaching.

http://jsfiddle.net/DrxFV/2/

```
var content1 = $('section.note div.content1').detach();
var content2 = $('section.note div.content2').detach();
$('section.note').html('').append(content1).append(content2);
```

Comment: Yes, IE always wins at being different. In this particular case I take it would be ok using either clone or detach since it is giving same output what I need?

Comment: I personally prefer detach because it'l move an existing element, while clone will create a new element and append it instead.